# I don't know where to go next! What should I do?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I was playing Pokémon Sun/Moon, but then I got confused at the directions I was given and I stopped playing for a while and now I can't remember where I'm supposed to go next. How can I know what my next objective is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the bottom screen of your 3DS, Rotom will give you a reminder of your next step every time your current objective changes or you load the game, and you can prompt Rotom to remind you where you're supposed to go by tapping the yellow face that displays your position on the map.

By tapping the map on the bottom screen anywhere but on the current position marker, you can open and view a full map of Alola, which displays a purple flag marker over your next destination.

Comment: Is this flag still there after you've defeated the top 4? I haven't seen it since.

Comment: @Jutschge Since there is no plot objective after finishing the main story, there is no purple flag in the postgame.

Comment: Well there is the UB Storyline which could be considered an additional "mini-story".

Comment: @Jutschge And that's not the main story, so it has no marker on the map.

Comment: @Jutschge For the Ultra Beast story, as long as you find Looker, he can remind you where you need to go next at any time.